# In Gin-Rummy, when both players Pass, can the active player make a Pickup?

Tags: gin-rummy

In Gin-Rummy, if both players pass the first face-up card, does the first player **must** Draw from the pile or she can Pickup the first discard?

Obviously, there is no benefit in first pass a card, then when the opponent also show no interset by passing, to pick it up, however, does the rules allow it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pagat](https://www.pagat.com/rummy/ginrummy.html) says the first player cannot go back and take the face up card but must draw from the stock:

> If both players refuse the turned-up card, the non-dealer draws the top card from the stock pile.

It seems to be the common rule.
[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gin_rummy), [Spruce Crafts](https://www.thesprucecrafts.com/gin-rummy-complete-card-game-rules-412366), [WikiHow](https://www.wikihow.com/Play-Gin-Rummy) all agree

Answer (score 0):

[Gin-Colony](https://www.gamecolony.com/gin_rummy_game_rules.shtml) state that after both players have passed the first player must Draw.  However I am not sure if that is a (common) house rule or a formal rule.

> If both players pass (refuse) the very first upcard, the non-dealer
>   must start a game by drawing the top card from the closed deck. He
>   adds this card to his hand and discards ANY card on top of the
>   original upcard to build the waste pile.